# Where to place the robots.txt file on jetty server?

Tags: jetty, robots.txt, embedded-jetty

I have recently started checking for the security vulnerabilities of our web application through a tool called Zap. After running it I came across that I've to include the robots.txt as well in our webapp.
The tool is looking for the file in the root directory of the webapp (https://localhost:8080) and the file is presented there, but it throws an error saying "file not found".
The webserver I am running is Jetty-9.3.8 and following is the tree structure of the webapp

```
etc 
   - webdefault.xml
webapps
   - myapp
          - web.xml
          - generated-web.xml
robots.txt
```

We're using embedded jetty to start the server. Like this:

```
    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/myapp");
    context.setWar(jettyHome + "/webapps/myapp/");
    context.setDefaultsDescriptor(jettyHome + "/etc/webdefault.xml");
    File overrideFile = new File(jettyHome
            + "/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/generated-web.xml");
    if (overrideFile.exists()) {
        context.setOverrideDescriptor(jettyHome
                + "/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/generated-web.xml");
    }

    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
```

So, how to place the file in the root directory isn't what I am getting.
Anybody has any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a something serving static content from the `contextPath` of `/` for that to work.

Add another `WebAppContext` or `ServletContextPath` or `ResourceHandler` to serve the file.  Make sure that you have ...

- `context.setContextPath("/")` set
- `context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource("uri/path/to/my/static/content")`